# Loopback 4 compound query string syntax

Tags: get, axios, loopbackjs

I am trying to put together a compound json query string using the where filter to access my loopback API. Simple or statements work when they are the only items in the query string.

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Parsing-requests.html

As an example the following query string will return the two correct ids:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/products?filter={"where":{"or":[{"ProductId": "AOC"},{"ProductId": "BCK"}]}}
```

But when I try to make it more complex such as trying to filter for all "flower" products that have a strain type of "I" or "H", I get a 400 error:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/products?filter=filter={"where":{"and":[{"ProductType": "flower"},{"or":[{"ProductStrain": "H"},{"ProductStrain": "I"}]}]}}
```

Same with:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/products?filter=filter={"where": {"ProductType": "flower"},{"or":[{"ProductStrain": "I"},{"ProductStrain": "H"}]}}
```

I am guessing that I have a syntax issue, but I have tried a dozen different ways and still haven't got what I want. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/products?**filter=filter**={"where":{" this is just copy/paste error?

Comment: yes, sorry, will update it

Comment: actually, you were right. feel really dumb right now.

Comment: What connector are you using? The queries looks correct to me according to https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Where-filter.html, this may be a connector-specific problem. Are you able to reproduce the problem using `memory` connector too?